# What Does mean NSConcreteScanner setScanLocation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**This is My Code:**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 productScreen *screen=[[productScreen alloc]init];
 screen =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"product"];
                [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

when ever i select the collection cell its give me a error .

**ERROR**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteScanner setScanLocation:]: Index 1 out of bounds; string length 0'

I searched many sites but i cant get the answer properly so any experts please help me to fix this error.

Comment: On which line is the error occurring? It also seems odd that you're instantiating the `productScreen` class (which should have an uppercase P by the way) to the `screen` variable, then immediately overwriting it with a view controller instantiated from the storyboard.

Comment: @SteveWilford this error coming when i have selected the collection view cell.

Comment: Yes you said that in the question, but specifically which line in that method?

Comment: I cant Specify From which line its giving me error...@SteveWilford

Comment: Where are you using a scanner? Or doing some string processing?

Comment: i have not using Scanner and String process is not there anything in productScreen.@Wain

Comment: @KishoreKumar Can you at least provide the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Friends Finally i have found my error...@SteveWilford @wain

Comment: i have left to give back ground colour here in productScreen self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@""];

Comment: so that the error arises @SteveWilford ,but what is the related between the error and that mistake

Comment: @SteveWilford any way thanks brother for your response....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
screen =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"product"];
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

the view is loaded. you then have code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@""];
```

which is trying to parse an invalid string and throwing an error.

Also, you should remove:

```
productScreen *screen=[[productScreen alloc]init];
```

because you're creating an instance of `productScreen` which is never used so it's a waste of memory, and your class `productScreen` should be called `ProductScreen` to follow naming conventions.

Comment: productScreen *screen=[[productScreen alloc]init]; i accept your answer because you gave me a some concepts thank lot @wain